# Wordpress blog problem

Tags: wordpress

I have developed whole my website in wordpress and my site url is like **'http://www.domain.com'** and now I have one blog link with my website and I want to give url like **'http://www.domain.com/blog'** how can I achieve this with wordpress? I have developed whole site in wordpress itself.

I want to keep one link say "http:/domain.com/blog" and I want to display my posts over there.

Please help me out.

Comment: this question should belong to WordPress Answers @ StackExchange

Comment: do you want to move your whole wordpress site in blog folder?

Comment: I dont want to move actually my site is made itself in wordpress and now, I want to keep one link say "http:/domain.com/blog" and I want to display my posts over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called Permalink in WordPress. Read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more information.